# Is it possible to edit a single tick label of a time series in Python?

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, time, time-series

I have been working with python for the first time and I am trying to plot some time series. I am using data of a few days and I want in the x-axis of the plot, whenever the day changes, to be visible. For instance, the x-axis is now

00:00  06:00  12:00  18:00  00:00 06:00 ... and so on

Is it possible to have the day visible below time at every 00:00 appeared? Something like this:

00:00  06:00  12:00  18:00  00:00 06:00

```
Mon                    Tue
```

And so on. Any advice?         ­­­­­­

Comment: You can definitely plot the `datetime` on the x-axis. I'm not sure about having a dual label on the x-axis like that besides maybe if you included Mon or Tue on all of them? Or you could place them there as text after you generate the plot? Here is a `datetime` plot example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html?highlight=datetime
But maybe you are looking for something more like this, except with weekdays instead of years? https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html?highlight=datetime

Comment: I think I have seen something like this with the pandas plotting function (which uses matplotlib behind the scenes).

Comment: @ThomasKühn I am using pandas. I am pretty sure I have also seen something like this but I can't find it.

Comment: It seems that got broken somehow in the current development version, see [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13618), but with any current version of matplotlib it should work fine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually it's pretty helpful. I am using TeX in the document and `"\n%a"` does not seem to work with it but I think I'll figure it out. Thanks.